# Install PyQt5 on Raspberry for Python3.6

Tags: python, installation, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3

Since I found no answer for my question, neither in older posts nor in other forums, I want to ask the stackoverflow community for advice.

I am using a raspberry pi 3B+, version 9.4 (lite) with kernel version 4.14.71-v7.

I use python3.6. I installed it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.6.0.tgz

sudo -s
cd Python-3.6.0
bash configure
make altinstall
exit
```

Installation was without any trouble and everything works perfectly.

Now I wanted to install the PyQt5 modul for python3.6. I usually use

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install ...
```

for installing a modul for python3.6. Trying

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install pyqt5
```

gave me the error message

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for PyQt5
```

So I tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-default pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools
```

But it installed PyQt5 for python3.5 (which is preinstalled) on the raspberry.

So does anybody know how to use or install PyQt5 for the subsequently installed
python3.6?

Edit 08.03.2019:
Thanks FlyingTeller. I started to build from source. I followed the steps from
your link.

```
sudo apt-get update
cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/sip-4.19.14.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf sip-4.19.14.tar.gz
cd sip-4.19.14
sudo -s
python3.6 configure.py --sip-module=PyQt5.sip 
make
make install

cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/PyQt5_gpl-5.12.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf PyQt5_gpl-5.12.tar.gz
cd PyQt5_gpl-5.12
python3.6 configure.py
```

Then I received the following error

```
Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.
```

I think I am on the right way, but I do not understand what qmake is or what it
means.

Edit 10.03.2019:
I could solve the last error message. I installed

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Then I did the same procedure as already mentioned. Now I get the error

```
fatal error: sip.h: File or directory not found 
#include <sip.h>
```

PyQt5 config.py is in: /usr/src/PyQt5_gpl-5.12
SIP sip.h is in: /usr/src/sip-4.19.14

Anybody an idea? Thanks guys.

Comment: are you using a `virtualenv`

Comment: Have you considered [building from source](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html)?

Comment: I am trying it but it has not worked yet. Check out the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I found the solution. The steps below worked for me, without any error. The whole process took almost two hours.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install sip-dev

cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/sip-4.19.14.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf sip-4.19.14.tar.gz
cd sip-4.19.14
sudo python3.6 configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip
sudo make
sudo make install

cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/PyQt5_gpl-5.12.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf PyQt5_gpl-5.12.tar.gz
cd PyQt5_gpl-5.12
sudo python3.6 configure.py
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: you would better use "sudo make -j4"

Comment: Why is that better?

Comment: By using "-j4" flag will increase the installation speed.

Comment: just for the benefit of someone who is curious, -j4 will divide the task to four CPU cores, thereby making teh installation faster.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they moved some things around.   This seems to work, as far as getting things, and compiling them.  It takes a long time to build.

For the associated designer, look at:

[QtDesigner for Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492720/qtdesigner-for-raspberry-pi/62815727#62815727)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install sip-dev

cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/4.19.23/sip-4.19.23.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf sip-4.19.23.tar.gz
cd sip-4.19.23
sudo python3 configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip
sudo make
sudo make install

cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/5.13.2/PyQt5-5.13.2.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf PyQt5-5.13.2.tar.gz
cd PyQt5-5.13.2
sudo python3  configure.py
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to update pip from verion 18 to the newest, in my case 20.2 (`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`) and then do a `pip install PyQt5`.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions used in the accepted answer did not work for me. I think it's simply because they are outdated. I wanted to post the list of commands that *did* work for me. I'm running a Pi 400 with the latest version of Raspbian as of 12/20/2020. I used the default `python3` rather than `python3.6`.

Here is the modified list of commands that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install sip-dev

cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/sip-5.5.1.dev2011271026.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf sip-5.5.1.dev2011271026.tar.gz
cd sip-5.5.1.dev2011271026
sudo python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install

sudo wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz
sudo tar xzf PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz
cd PyQt5-5.15.2
sudo python3 configure.py
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment due to reputation but I would add to Christ Troutner's useful updated answer, that in case users get a `No module named 'PyQt5.sip'` error, try --sip-module PyQt5.sip during configure, per the docs:

> Note
>
> When building PyQt5 v5.11 or later you must configure SIP to create a
> private copy of the sip module using a command line similar to the
> following:
>
> python configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip
>
> If you already have SIP installed and you just want to build and
> install the private copy of the module then add the --no-tools option.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answers did not work for me, below is the code that worked for me.

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install qt5-default
   sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

This code not only installs Qtcreator but also installs Qt5 Assistant, Qt5 Designer, and Qt5 Linguist