# Running PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi - "PyQt5._QOpenGLFunctions_ES2" error

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, raspbian, debian-buster

I am facing a problem running PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi 4.

I use raspberry pi 4, version 10 (buster) kernel version 4.19.75-v71.

The default python is 3.7.3.

I followed the exact same steps of installing sip and PyQt5 as mentioned on this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062050/install-pyqt5-on-raspberry-for-python3-6). I also installed python 3.6.0 following the steps introduced on the aforementioned thread.

After finishing the installation without any error, and when I run my code, I face the following error message:

```
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin

QEGLPlatformContext: Failed to create context: 3009

QOpenGLWindow::beginPaint: Failed to create context

QOpenGLWindow::beginPaint: Failed to make context current

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "my_code.py", line 68, in initializeGL

    self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions()

AttributeError: module 'PyQt5._QOpenGLFunctions_ES2' has no attribute 'QOpenGLFunctions_ES2'

Aborted
```

Any guidance how to overcome this problem? Much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS the code is running smoothly on Win10. Thus, the code itself must have no problem. (the environment on Win10 is: numpy=1.14.3; numpy-stl=2.5.0; pyqt5=5.10.1; sip=4.19.8; six=1.11.0; python=3.6.0; python-utils=2.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to reinstall pyqt5 to fix this problem. look if there are a thread is occupy pip/pyqt5/qmake.exe.
Or look you GPU, does it is OpenGL2.0 or higher version?

you said that the problems was made by
"self.gl=self.context().versionFunctions()"
And I was writhing an example, you can try it:

```
    import sys
    import math
    from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize, Qt
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QOpenGLWidget, QSlider,
                                 QWidget)
    
    import OpenGL.GL as gl
    
    
    class Window(QWidget):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super(Window, self).__init__()
    
            self.glWidget = GLWidget()
    
            self.xSlider = self.createSlider()
            self.ySlider = self.createSlider()
            self.zSlider = self.createSlider()
    
            self.xSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.glWidget.setXRotation)
            self.glWidget.xRotationChanged.connect(self.xSlider.setValue)
            self.ySlider.valueChanged.connect(self.glWidget.setYRotation)
            self.glWidget.yRotationChanged.connect(self.ySlider.setValue)
            self.zSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.glWidget.setZRotation)
            self.glWidget.zRotationChanged.connect(self.zSlider.setValue)
    
            mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.xSlider)
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.ySlider)
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.zSlider)
            self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    
            self.xSlider.setValue(15 * 16)
            self.ySlider.setValue(345 * 16)
            self.zSlider.setValue(0 * 16)
    
            self.setWindowTitle("Hello GL")
    
        def createSlider(self):
            slider = QSlider(Qt.Vertical)
    
            slider.setRange(0, 360 * 16)
            slider.setSingleStep(16)
            slider.setPageStep(15 * 16)
            slider.setTickInterval(15 * 16)
            slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksRight)
    
            return slider
    
    
    class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
        xRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
        yRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
        zRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    
            self.object = 0
            self.xRot = 0
            self.yRot = 0
            self.zRot = 0
    
            self.lastPos = QPoint()
    
            self.trolltechGreen = QColor.fromCmykF(0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            self.trolltechPurple = QColor.fromCmykF(0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0)
    
        def getOpenglInfo(self):
            info = """
                Vendor: {0}
                Renderer: {1}
                OpenGL Version: {2}
                Shader Version: {3}
            """.format(
                gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VENDOR),
                gl.glGetString(gl.GL_RENDERER),
                gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VERSION),
                gl.glGetString(gl.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)
            )
    
            return info
    
        def minimumSizeHint(self):
            return QSize(50, 50)
    
        def sizeHint(self):
            return QSize(400, 400)
    
        def setXRotation(self, angle):
            angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
            if angle != self.xRot:
                self.xRot = angle
                self.xRotationChanged.emit(angle)
                self.update()
    
        def setYRotation(self, angle):
            angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
            if angle != self.yRot:
                self.yRot = angle
                self.yRotationChanged.emit(angle)
                self.update()
    
        def setZRotation(self, angle):
            angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
            if angle != self.zRot:
                self.zRot = angle
                self.zRotationChanged.emit(angle)
                self.update()
    
        def initializeGL(self):
            print(self.getOpenglInfo())
    
            self.setClearColor(self.trolltechPurple.darker())
            self.object = self.makeObject()
            gl.glShadeModel(gl.GL_FLAT)
            gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
            gl.glEnable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE)
    
        def paintGL(self):
            gl.glClear(
                gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            gl.glLoadIdentity()
            gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
            gl.glRotated(self.xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            gl.glRotated(self.yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            gl.glRotated(self.zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            gl.glCallList(self.object)
    
        def resizeGL(self, width, height):
            side = min(width, height)
            if side  360 * 16:
                angle -= 360 * 16
            return angle
    
        def setClearColor(self, c):
            gl.glClearColor(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())
    
        def setColor(self, c):
            gl.glColor4f(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

before try this example, please run this command(install pyOpenGL):
pip install pyOpenGL